# Are foam filters in return important?

Tags: hvac

I recently got all my hvac replaced, and in the returns were these black foam filters. Unfortunately, the drywallers sprayed texture all over them.  I didn't have these in my old returns, but it still seems prudent to replace them. My question is two-fold -- How important are they, and where can I find replacements?  Googling for them turns up nothing and I wasn't able to find anything like them (size-wise, at least) at Home Depot. [image: foam filter]

Answer (score 1):

these are an aftermarket filter designed to reduce dust and debris entering your ductwork at the intake vent.  they aren't necessary - your furnace filter will keep the air clean before it gets to the fan and heat exchanger.  in my experience, the vent filters do nothing except retard air flow and reduce the efficiency of the system.  don't bother with them, do bother with a new furnace filter every 3-4 months - twice as often as suggested.